# How do you display multiple checkbox fields in the edit view of the Administrate dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, administrate

I have multiple checkboxes for one of my fields on a user model. The checkbox selections are currently stored as an array. I'm trying to recreate the multiple checkboxes in the edit view of the Administrate dashboard for the user but not sure how (options in the docs don't seem to cover this).

Here is migration introducing the field:

```
class AddEmploymentTypesToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :employment_types, :text, array:true, default: []
  end
end
```

The UI from my User form that I want to recreate in the dashboard edit view:
[image]

Code for that form:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="font-weight-bold" for="">What type of employment are you looking for?</label>
        <br>
        <%= f.check_box :employment_types, { :multiple => true }, 'Full-time', nil%> Full-time
        <br>
        <%= f.check_box :employment_types, { :multiple => true }, 'Part-time', nil%> Part-time
        <br>
        <%= f.check_box :employment_types, { :multiple => true }, 'Freelance', nil%> Freelance
        <br>
        <%= f.check_box :employment_types, { :multiple => true }, 'Contract-to-hire', nil%> Contract-to-hire
      </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to provide a custom field type for this, as the ones that Administrate provide are not good here. I'm pretty sure that the reason for this is that this sort of field can be implemented in many ways, so Administrate can't provide a single, unified solution.

To create a new field, inherit from `Administrate::Field::Base`:

```rb
### app/fields/checkbox_list.rb
class CheckboxList < Administrate::Field::Base
  def self.permitted_attribute(attr, _options = nil)
    # Yes, this has to be a hash rocket `=>`,
    # not a colon `:`. Otherwise it will be the key
    # `attr` (literally) as opposed to a key whose name
    # is the value of the argument `attr`.
    { attr => [] }
  end

  def choices
    options[:choices]
  end
end
```

For your specific case, I'm implementing two methods. I'll explain them individually.

First, there is `self.permitted_attribute`. This is an API that Administrate internally uses to figure out how to translate your new field type into terms of `params.require(...).permit(...)`.

Because your field is modelled as a list of checkboxes, `params` will see it as an array:

```rb
params[:user]
# => { name: "Conway Anderson", employment_types: ["Freelance", "Contract-to-hire"] }
```

To tell `permit` to accept this, normally you do this in a Rails app:

```rb
params.require(:user).permit(:name, employment_types: [])
```

By implementing the `CheckboxList.permitted_attributes` as I did above, Administrate passes the right information (`employment_types: []`) to permit: it's saying to permit `employment_types` which will be an array value. You are probably doing this in your application somewhere else already?

That's for the first method! Now the second: `choices`. This reads from `options`, which is the list of options provided to the field in the dashboard defintion. So for example here:

```rb
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
  id: Field::Number,
  name: Field::String,
  # ...
  employment_types: CheckboxList.with_options(choices: ['Full-time', 'Part-time', 'Freelance', 'Contract-to-hire']),
}.freeze
```

That way, `CheckboxList` can be reused for different lists of choices. Note that I'm not using the word `options` because it's used internally by `Administrate::Field::Base` already, and that would conflict.

Moving on, your field also requires template partials, to tell Rails how to render it. These go in the `views/` folder, and can look for example like this:

```
### app/views/fields/checkbox_list/_index.html.erb
<%= field.data.join(', ') %>
```

```
### app/views/fields/checkbox_list/_show.html.erb
<%= field.data.join(', ') %>
```

```
### app/views/fields/checkbox_list/_form.html.erb
<div class="field-unit__label">
  <%= f.label field.attribute %>
</div>
<div class="field-unit__field">
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes field.attribute, field.choices, :itself, :itself %>
</div>
```

The trickiest one is the form. Note that I use `field.choices`, which is the same method `choices` defined in the class `CheckboxList`, and that reads from the options given in the dashboard.

And I think that's it! Add the new field and type to your dashboard (and don't forget to add it to `SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES`, `FORM_ATTRIBUTES`, etc), and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

`check_box_tag` is what you are looking for. Read more [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag)

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="font-weight-bold" for="">What type of employment are you looking for?</label>
  <% ['Full-time', 'Part-time', 'Freelance', 'Contract-to-hire'].each do |type| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "put_your_form_model_here[employment_types][]", type, uniq_number_that_you_want_for_each_type %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the specific connection between this and Administrate. Am I wrong? I see that this seems like a better way to write the form, but the existing form is working. The challenge is configuring Administrate to display a similar form and multiple checkboxes in the dashboard.

Comment: You want the checkbox to be checked if the index value is stored in the DB right?

Comment: I do want that but right now I'm not able to get these multiple checkboxes to display at all in the administrate dashboard. And there's no multiple checkbox option in the docs.

Comment: can you show the code of **administrate dashboard** view